# Invalid use of property in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I've been following a tutorial on Youtube for an employee manager, It uses a lot of features that i don't need so I've been trying to pick out parts that it need.
I have no experience with VBA or coding so I'm struggling to work out why certain things wont work.

The Screenshots have annotations of the intended results.

Than you in advance

[Example and annotations of intended result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O70VJ.png)

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tNOD6.png)

[Debug view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oAFIG.png)

**Here are my Macros for the buttons and the refresh**

```
Option Explicit

Public EventRow As Long
Public EventCol As Long
Public MapRng As String

Sub Event_SaveNew()

    With Sheet6
    
        'check req fields
        If Sheet3.Range("g3").Value = Empty Or Sheet3.Range("g5").Value = Empty Then
        
            MsgBox ("Event Name and Event Type are required fields for ANY Event")
            Exit Sub
            
        End If
        
        EventRow = .Range("E2000").End(xlUp).Row + 1 'first av row
        .Cells(EventRow, 5).Value = Sheet3.Range("b7").Value 'new event id
        
        For EventCol = 6 To 12
        
            .Cells(EventRow, EventCol).Value = Sheet3.Range(.Cells(1, EventCol).Value).Value 'event feild
            
        Next EventCol
        
    End With
    
    With Sheet3
    
        .Range("B2").Value = False               'set new event to false
        .Range("B4").Value = Sheet6.Cells(EventRow, 1).Value 'New event ID
        Event_Refresh
        'reload events
    End With
    
End Sub

Sub Event_Refresh()

    Dim LastEventRow As Long
    Dim LastFiltRow As Long
    
    With Sheet3
    
        'load Events list into events sheet using adv filter and sort
        .Range("f22:m2000").ClearContents        'clear existing events list
        LastEventRow = Sheet6.Range("e2000").End(xlUp).Row + 6
        Sheet6.Range ("e4:L" & LastEventRow)
        
    End With
    
End Sub

Sub Event_AddNew()
    With Sheet3
    
        .Range("B1").Value = True                'set event load to true
        .Range("b2").Value = True                'set new event to true
        .Range("J7,j5,g5,g3,f11:j17,g7,g8,j3").ClearContents
        .Range("b1").Value = False               'set event load to false
        .Range("G3").Select
        
    End With
    
End Sub

Sub Event_Load()
    Dim SelRow As Long
    
    With Sheet3
    
        SelRow = .Range("b9").Value
        
        If .Range("B3").Value = Empty Then
        
            MsgBox "Please select on an Event to display Event details"
            
            Exit Sub
        End If
        
        .Range("b1").Value = True                'set empload to true
        EventRow = .Range("b3").Value
        
    End With
    
    With Sheet6
    
        For EventCol = 6 To 12
        
            MapRng = Sheet6.Cells(1, EventCol).Value
            .Range(MapRng).Value = Sheet6.Cells(EventRow, EventCol).Value 'add maped values
            
        Next EventCol
        
    End With
    
    With Sheet3
    
        .Range("B2").Value = False               'set new event to false
        .Range("B1").Value = False               'set event load to false
        
    End With
    
End Sub

Sub Event_Delete()

    If MsgBox("Are you sure you want to DELETE this event?", vbYesNo, "Delete Event") = vbNo Then Exit Sub
    
    With Sheet3
    
        If .Range("B3").Value = Empty Then Exit Sub
        
        EventRow = .Range("B3").Value            'event row
        Sheet6.Range(EventRow & ":" & EventRow).EntireRow.Delete
        Event_Refresh                            'refresh events
        
    End With
    
End Sub

Sub Event_CancelNew()

    With Sheet3
    
        .Range("b2").Value = False
        Sheet3.Range("F22").Select
        
    End With
    
End Sub
```

And here is the code for the Event log page

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim MapRng As Range
    Dim FoundMapRng As Range
    Dim CellAdd As String
    Dim SellRow As Long
    
    'exsisting event change update event tab
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("F3:L17")) Is Nothing And Range("B2").Value = False And Range("B1").Value = False And IsNumeric(Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column + 25).Value) = True And Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column + 25).Value <> Empty Then
        
        Sheet6.Cells(Range("b3").Value, Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column + 25).Value).Value = Target.Value
        
    End If
    
    'update below
    CellAdd = Target.Address
    SellRow = Range("b9").Value
    Set MapRng = Sheet3.Range("EventDataMap")
    Set FoundMapRng = MapRng.Find(CellAdd, , xlValues, xlWhole)
    If Not FoundMapRng Is Nothing Then Cells(SellRow, FoundMapRng.Column).Value = Sheet6.Cells(Range("b3").Value, Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column + 25).Value).Value
    
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    
    'on table selection
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("F22:M2000")) Is Nothing And Range("f" & Target.Row).Value <> Empty Then
    
        Range("b9").Value = Target.Row           'add in selection row
        Range("b4").Value = Range("f" & Target.Row).Value 'add event ID
        Event_Load
        
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Comment: What are you trying to do here ?  'Sheet6.Range ("e4:L" & LastEventRow)'

Comment: As far as I know this is the filled out data on the event list that is then to be put into the the event log page.

Comment: You need to have something after, like you had before: `Sheet6.Range("e3:L" & LastEventRow).AdvancedFilter xlFilterCopy, , CopyToRange:=Sheet6.Range("R3:Y3"), Unique:=True`. The line with the range function expects you to do something with the range, i.e. filter, copy, select etc... This would work too: `Sheet1.Range("e4:L" & LastEventRow).Select`. But as @freeflow mentions, what do you want the line to do? Filter the range? copy range?

Comment: Thank you for the help I worked it out now, I've got it to copy the data then paste it into the Event log sheet.

Comment: But now I have a new problem, either with the save, or refresh macro. I'm going to post a new question with details.

Comment: The new question is up, I value your help.